# Can I browse to my ASP.NET application on an Azure VM using an IP address?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis-7

I have a web site on a cloud server within my domain, which hosts a website with a url like `http://myserver`. I cannot access ASP.NET by IP address but I can by the server name.

I can get the ip address of the server
C:\Users\me>ping myserver

Pinging myserver.mydomain.com [123.7.141.2] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 123.7.141.2: bytes=32 time=55ms TTL=121
Reply from 123.7.141.2: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=121
Reply from 123.7.141.2: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=121
Reply from 123.7.141.2: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=121

Ping statistics for 123.7.141.2:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 55ms, Average = 37ms

My expectation is that `https://123.7.141.2` would allow me to browse successfully to the site as `https://myserver` does work.

The existing bindings in IIS 7 were
type    hostname    port    ip address
http    myserver    80  *
http    myserver    443 *

I added the following bindings

http    myserver    80  123.7.141.2
http    myserver    443 123.7.141.2

When I run ipconfig on myserver I get the following information
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : myservername.d1.internal.cloudapp.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 123.7.141.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.224
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 123.7.141.1

Tunnel adapter isatap.myservername.d1.internal.cloudapp.net:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : myservername.d1.internal.cloudapp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bindings force IIS to wait for request with hostname=myserver. Try creating bindings like:

```
type hostname port ip
http    *      80  *
```

This will allow IIS to serve your site even for requests without hostname and just IP.

Comment: Thanks. It's the nuances that get me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have opened port 80 for external access to your VM in the Azure Management Console.  Check the endpoints section on your VM page.